davfs2 segfault when browsing with Nautilus and Ubuntu 24.04
After updating to Ubuntu 24.04 with Gnome 46, Nautilus (files) shows the following error when browsing a davfs share: error opening directory 'transfer endpoint is not connected'
This effectively kills the mount and I find back the following in the logs:
kernel: mount.davfs[8855]: segfault at 0 ip 00007814bc044055 sp 00007ffee3439c30 error 4 in libneon.so.27.6.0[7814bc03e000+18000] likely on CPU 4 (core 0, socket 0)
kernel: Code: 56 41 55 41 54 41 89 f4 41 83 e4 01 53 48 89 fb 41 f7 dc 66 41 81 e4 83 73 44 89 e0 48 83 ec 18 80 cc 40 83 e6 02 44 0f 45 e0 <0f> b6 07 84 c0 0f 84 c8 00 00 00 48 89 fa 4>
gnome-shell[3479]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2200214
nautilus[47494]: g_object_weak_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

If I browse from a terminal this does not happen so it seems related to nautilus although the segmentation fault is thrown by davfs. Any idea how to get around this?

Same problem. Have you found any solution or have you filled a bug report with Ubuntu?

Just reported the bug to Canonical: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/davfs2/+bug/2070245 and to the original author: https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/index.php?65914

No solution so far except for reverting to terminal use. I'm unsure as to where to report the bug officially, I though the Ubuntu forums but there my post has seen zero reaction: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2498046
